# ffmpeg slideshow piping input and output for image stream

Tags: unix, ffmpeg

I am trying to make from a list of images a video and then I will directly upload it. 
I have managed so far to create a video for the images with:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -r 1 -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - foo.mp4
```

It works well and I'm happy with it. However, now I would like to pipe the output and I can't really manage to do this. I've tried a couple of like:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 1/5 -vcodec mjpeg -i - pipe:1 | cat > p.mpeg
```

(for the moment I would just like to pipe back in a file just to test and then I'll had the direct upload).

I've read in another thread that I should specify the output format which makes sense as the error returned by ffmpeg is "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:1'". However, all I can find in the doc is:

```
-f fmt (input/output)
Force input or output file format. The format is normally auto detected 
for input files and guessed from the file extension for output files, 
so this option is not needed in most cases.
```

How can I specify the output format and the input format?

Comment: where did you get the idea to use `pipe:1`? I've never seen that used in a unix cmd line. Is it something you found in the doc for ffmpeg? Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly set some output format. Which one doesn't really matter, but after `-i`, you need:

- a `-c:v copy` to just copy the JPEG stream
- a `-f format`
- `-` as the output pipe

From my experience `matroska` works fine as an output format.

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 1/5 -c:v mjpeg -i - -c:v copy -f matroska - | ffplay -
```

I just tested this and it runs without issues. The file plays in VLC as well when you do `| cat > out.mkv` instead of the `ffplay` call.

Comment: Hey I looked into it and made this worked `cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 1 -c:v mjpeg -i - -c:v libx264 -r 7 -f mpegts - | cat > foo.mpeg` thanks to you. Btw I am planning to get base64 images in input and output in a video format easily readable what options do you recommend? Thx again

Comment: Glad it worked. What's "easily readable" depends on what you need to do with it and how you're reading it.

Comment: Well lambda web user are likely to download it to read it one their laptop (not browser) so I don't want it to be in an obscure codec that only vlc and friends can read.

Comment: That's not easy. Modern OSes will play H.264 video and AAC audio in MP4 containers. Others will take MPEG-4 (Part II) video and MP3 audio. Use `libx264` and `libfdk_aac` or `mpeg-4` and `libmp3lame` as encoders, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your example to work at the moment, so I haven't tested this. But I'll bet you can set the output format by putting -f *after* the "-i -".  (i.e. -f is stateful and sets the format for the next input/output.)

Comment: Hm I've tried it `cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 1/5 -vcodec mjpeg -i - -f matroska pipe:1 | cat > p.mkv` it sorts of work: it creates the file when I open it with vlc I get the first image but then the length is not defined and the file seems obviously corrupted... Anymore idea?